# Why cant I move JLabel Icon?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel

Why cant I change the x and y coordinates of the icon? All I really need is to add the image to the screen. Do I even need to use a JLabel?

```
package bit;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class BIT extends JFrame
{
    JLabel CL;

    public BIT()
    {
        CL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("final-image.jpg")));
        CL.setBounds(0,0,100,100);

        this.getContentPane().add(CL);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(5,5,1000,500);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new BIT();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Unset the layout of the JFrame before adding controls with setBounds

```
this.setLayout(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the x & y coordinates of the `JLabel` as the `JFrame` is using its default [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) layout manager which arranges its components according to layout implementation.

`setBounds` only works when using absolute positioning (or `null` layout) and [this option should be avoided(!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing).

It appears you are trying to position the `JLabel` in the top left-hand corner of the frame (`0, 0`). To do this you could:

- Left-align the label
- Add the label in the `PAGE_START` position

This would be:

```
CL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(...), JLabel.LEFT);
this.getContentPane().add(CL, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```